# ldapsearch fails to establisch secure connection

Tags: ssl, ldap

I'm trying to connect to LDAP server using SSL, but it fails.

```
ldapsearch -d 1 -Z -D "cn=root,dc=westr" -w ldappwd
```

But I get always

```
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

I tried to turn off the certificate check (TLS_REQCERT allow/never) and to use the certificate of the server (TLS_CACERT /path/to/file.cer), but it didn't help.

Then i checked logs on the server and found something confusing:

> 21        TLS: error: accept - error - received non-SSL message [0x30]
>
> 22        TLS: can't accept: TLS error -12261:SSL received a malformed Hello Request handshake message..
>
> 23        5bd6e432 connection_read(29): TLS accept failure error=-1 id=1014, closing
>
> 24        5bd6e432 connection_closing: readying conn=1014 sd=29 for close
>
> 25        5bd6e432 connection_close: conn=1014 sd=29
>
> 26        5bd6e432 daemon: removing 29
>
> 27        5bd6e432 conn=1014 fd=29 closed (TLS negotiation failure)

Apache Directory Studio works with this server without problems. Have anybody ideas how to make ldapsearch work with the server?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1
The initioal connection is successfull. As I already mentioned, there is some problem with establishing TLS (the server closes the connection with TLS: can't accept: TLS error -12261:SSL received a malformed Hello Request handshake message..).

```
venom@serv$ ldapsearch -d 1 -Z -D "cn=root,dc=iswga" -w "pass"
ldap_create
ldap_extended_operation_s
ldap_extended_operation
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 10.10.0.100:636
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 10.10.0.100:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
ber_flush2: 31 bytes to sd 3
ldap_result ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 Connections:
* host: 10.10.0.100  port: 636  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Thu Nov  1 14:03:52 2018


** ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x7fffd1c2ae90 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ldap_err2string
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_send_server_request
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_free_connection: actually freed
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? In particular: Which OpenLDAP builds are used for command `ldapsearch`?

Comment: Please read this [Red Hat doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/9.0/html/administration_guide/ldap-clients-ssl) on the parameters to use. In short : specify -H, or -h and -p. Try also -ZZ.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04.1. Host and port are specified in /etc/ldap/ldap.conf. The initial connection is successfull.